# Show email as starred

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I show email as starred using javascript?Suppose I have an email 
**abcdefg@stackoverflow.com**, I am to show it as **a*****g@stackoverflow.com**. Can someone help me achieve this?

I can do this but I want a better method to achieve this

```
email = email.split('@');
username = email[0];
var str = '',i;
for(i=0;i<username.length;i++){
    if(i!=0) {
        str+= '*'
     }
     else
        str+=username[i]
};
email[0] = str;
var result = email.join('@');
```

Comment: Better in what respect?  Also bear in mind that if you're doing this on the client, then the unobfuscated version will be available to the user anyway.

Comment: Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for brevity:

ES6:

```
email.replace(/^(.)(.*)(.@.*)/, (...a) => a[1] + a[2].replace(/./g, '*') + a[3]);
```

ES5:

```
email.replace(/^(.)(.*)(.@.*)/,
    function(m, a1, a2, a3) { return a1 + a2.replace(/./g, '*') + a3 }
);
```

Given an email `abcdef@example.com`, the regex splits the string into 3 parts: `['a', 'bcde', 'f@example.com']`. The callback then puts it back together, replacing all characters of the second chunk with asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

Better as in shorter? More readable? This is the shortest I could come up with that is not very readable:

```
let email = "abcdefg@stackoverflow.com" 
let at = email.indexOf("@")
return email[0] 
       + email.substring(1, at).replace(/./g, "*") 
       + email.substring(at, email.length)
```